# How to reset Epson TM T88V to the factory factory settings?

Tags: thermal-printer, epson

Something weird happened with my printer. I can not login to web interface **192.168.192.168/webconfig**. Also, I can not ping it. I tried to reset it to factory settings with pushing the reset button on the back side of the printer. It did not work. Maybe someone faced the same issue before. How can I bring my printer IP settings back?

Comment: Well this sucks, I have exactly the same problem. And powering it on with the reset button pressed doesn’t do anything. Having the reset button pressed and powering it on for over a minute with the reset still pressed, the printer does nothing. If I try and count out a period of time longer than 5 seconds and less than 10, still nothing ever happens.

Answer (score 2):

I tried that technique as well but that seems to apply to only some models.

I followed the instructions I found here:
https://support.revelsystems.com/hc/en-us/articles/204186869-How-to-Reset-and-Configure-an-Epson-Printer

1. Turn the printer off
2. Use a paper clip or tip of a pen to press and hold the
   reset on the back of the printer.
3. While holding the reset button, turn the printer on.
4. Continue to hold the reset button. After 5 seconds, a warning will print out.  Release the reset button.

The warning would say:

> Resetting to Factory Default!
>
> Please Wait...
>
> WARNING: DO NOT TURN OFF POWER
>
> -
>
> -

After 5 minutes I would turn it off and then turn it back on, and I would confirm that the reset worked.

Comment: Works for me! Very important for uses of the "German fiscal element" as this resets some of the values (Secretkey) which you need to connect to the fiscal device.